# Exclude property from WebApi OData (EF) response in c#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm working with a WebApi project in C# (EF code first) and I'm using OData.
I have a "User" model with Id, Name, LastName, Email, and Password.

In controller for example I have this code:

```
// GET: odata/Users
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<User> GetUsers()
{
    return db.Users;
}
```

If I call /odata/Users I'll get all the data: Id, Name, LastName, Email, and Password.

How can I exclude Password from results but keep available in controller to make Linq queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a craft and temporary solution to this problem (is not the best solution because UserInfo is not an entity type and not support $select or $expand).
I created a new model called UserInfo just with the properties I need (apart of User):

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Then I changed the method in the controller:

```
// GET: odata/Users
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<UserInfo> GetUsers()
{
    List<UserInfo> lstUserInfo = new List<UserInfo>();

    foreach(User usr in db.Users)
    {
        UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
        userInfo.Id = usr.Id;
        userInfo.Name = usr.Name;
        userInfo.Email = usr.Email;

        lstUserInfo.Add(userInfo);
    }

    return lstUserInfo.AsQueryable();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this break the IQueryable design? What if you want 5 records out of 10,000,000?

Comment: [Automapper](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html) has ProjectTo() extension method for IQueryable that will not break design

Answer (score 18):

I'm a little late to the topic but I think this might help you out.

I assume that you will want to encrypt the password for storage purposes.  Have you looked at using an odata action to set the password?  Using an action lets you ignore the password property when setting up your entities while still exposing a clean way to the end user to update the password.

first: ignore the password property

```
builder.EntitySet<UserInfo>("UserInfo").EntityType.Ignore(ui => ui.Password);
```

second: add your odata action

```
builder.EntityType<UserInfo>().Action("SetPassword").Returns<IHttpActionResult>();
```

Then add the SetPassword method to your UserInfoController.

Comment: That's not a good solution. As I said I need Password available in the EDM!!! I just want to remove it from the response!

Comment: I guess i'm confused as to what you mean by "available in the EDM".  This solution allows you to access the password property in the api and removes it from the payload.

Comment: I just need to have access to the password inside a method in the controller but I don't want to show it into the response (when I return the User object). When I say that I need this available in the EDM I just say that I need to work with the password in the controller (work with linq queries, etc).

Comment: This is the correct solution, imo. As I understand your goal, you want to work with `User` in your controller and not need the extra `UserInfo` mapping class. With this solution you can. Drop `UserInfo` and expose `User` directly. Then apply @RickWillis solution on the `User` entity, this will result in the Password not be exposed in the OData payload.

Answer (score 13):

> How can I exclude Password from results but keep available in controller to make Linq queries?

Ignore it. From [Security Guidance for ASP.NET Web API 2 OData](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-security-guidance):

> There are two ways to exlude a property from the EDM. You can set the
>   [IgnoreDataMember] attribute on the property in the model class:
>
> ```
> public class Employee
> {
>     public string Name { get; set; }
>     public string Title { get; set; }
>     [IgnoreDataMember]
>     public decimal Salary { get; set; } // Not visible in the EDM
> }
> ```
>
> You can also remove the property from the EDM programmatically:
>
> ```
> var employees = modelBuilder.EntitySet<Employee>("Employees");
> employees.EntityType.Ignore(emp => emp.Salary);
> ```

Comment: Thanks but I've seen that documentation two days ago. If I try with [IgnoreDataMember] I will not have access to the Password in the EDM so that's not working for me. I can't remove the property programmatically from controller because the EDM is defined into WebApiConfig.cs. As I said I need this visible into the EDM but not in the response.

Comment: What does that mean? Entity Framework should still allow you to query it.

Comment: If you exclude the property from EDM this is not going to appear into the GET response (this is OK), but if you try for example to make a POST to create a new User in the API the password will be not received because that property is not part of the EDM. That's why I need to hide the password only for responses but not all the EDM (I think the only solution is to create a new class just with the parameters that I need only for responses).

Comment: @Martin, Use separate model for CreateUserCommand and UserInfoQuery

Comment: @MaulikModi I tried, but it does not work: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/2517

Comment: @Martín Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 9):

It might be a little late, but an elegant solution would be to add a custom QueryableSelectAttribute and then simply list the fields that you want selected on the serve-side. In your case it will look something like this:

```
public class QueryableSelectAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private const string ODataSelectOption = "$select=";
    private string selectValue;

    public QueryableSelectAttribute(string select)
    {
        this.selectValue = select;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);

        var request = actionContext.Request;
        var query = request.RequestUri.Query.Substring(1);
        var parts = query.Split('&').ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < parts.Count; i++)
        {
            string segment = parts[i];
            if (segment.StartsWith(ODataSelectOption, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                parts.Remove(segment);
                break;
            }
        }

        parts.Add(ODataSelectOption + this.selectValue);

        var modifiedRequestUri = new UriBuilder(request.RequestUri);
        modifiedRequestUri.Query = string.Join("&", parts.Where(p => p.Length > 0));
        request.RequestUri = modifiedRequestUri.Uri;

        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

And in the controller you simply add the attribute with the desired properties:

```
[EnableQuery]
[QueryableSelect("Name,LastName,Email")]
public IQueryable<User> GetUsers()
{
    return db.Users;
}
```

And that's it!

Of course the same principle can be applied for a custom `QueryableExpandAttribute`.

Comment: This is also a very interesting idea for a sort of "Permission Attribute" where only certain properties/expands can be returned depending on permissions.

Comment: this is the only thing that worked for me. However, unfortunately, it removes the "$select" clause from the request URI itself. So if I want to filter the fields down to only Name and LastName, it will return ALL the fields - Name,LastName,Email - anyway :-(

Comment: Another disadvantage is that every time I add a new property to my DTO, I have to change its [QueryableSelect("")] attribute on every method in my TableController.

Answer (score 7):

Add [NotMapped] attribute on the Password property in User Class as following:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string LastName {get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string Password {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Maya, that's not working for me because as I said in my post I need to keep the property available in the controller to make linq queries. If I try with NotMapped the property will be no present in the entity model. I need that property but I just want to hide it from API responses.

Comment: Maya's solution is for ignoring the property from OData query but still serializing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is make an odata controller that returns a projected subset of the original entity.

```
//in WebApi Config Method
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<FullEntity>("FullData");
builder.EntitySet<SubsetEntity>("SubsetData");
config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());


config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "DefaultApi",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "GET" }
);
SetupJsonFormatters();
config.Filters.Add(new UncaughtErrorHandlingFilterAttribute());
```

... then have two Odata Controllers one for FulLData, one for SubsetData (with different security),

```
namespace myapp.Web.OData.Controllers
{
    public class SubsetDataController : ODataController
    {
        private readonly IWarehouseRepository<FullEntity> _fullRepository;
        private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

        public SubsetDataController(
            IWarehouseRepository<fullEntity> fullRepository,
            IUserRepository userRepository
            )
        {
            _fullRepository = fullRepository;
            _userRepository = userRepository;
        }

public IQueryable<SubsetEntity> Get()
        {
            Object webHostHttpRequestContext = Request.Properties["MS_RequestContext"];
            System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal principal =
                (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal)
                    webHostHttpRequestContext.GetType()
                        .GetProperty("Principal")
                        .GetValue(webHostHttpRequestContext, null);
            if (!principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                throw new Exception("user is not authenticated cannot perform OData query");

            //do security in here

            //irrelevant but this just allows use of data by Word and Excel.
            if (Request.Headers.Accept.Count == 0)
                Request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/atom+xml");

            return _fullRepository.Query().Select( b=>
                    new SubsetDataListEntity
                    {
                        Id = b.Id,
                        bitofData = b.bitofData
                    }
          } //end of query
   } //end of class
```

Comment: Where does the Query() method come from?

Comment: This code assumes you return public IQueryable<EntityName> Query() from your database context. In other words in Query() do a query on you dbcontext as context.Set<EntityName>().AsQueryable();

Answer (score 1):

**You already tried this?**

Just update the property.

```
[EnableQuery]
public async Task<IQueryable<User>> GetUsers()
{
    var users = db.User;

    await users.ForEachAsync(q => q.Password = null);

    return users;
}
```

Comment: What is "db.User"? Where do I find the "db" variable? 
If I use "Query()" instead, this will raise an exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncEnumerable<MyType>. Only sources that implement IDbAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations. For more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=287068.'

Answer (score 1):

We can take advantage of the [ConventionModelBuilder](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#02-04-convention-model-builder) and use DataContract/DataMember to explicitly enable properties to be in the EdmModel.

> DataContract & DataMember
>
> Rule: If using DataContract or DataMember, only property with [DataMember] attribute will be added into Edm model.

Note, that this doesn't affect the EntityFramework model since we are not using the [NotMapped] attribute (unless you don't want it in either model)

```
[DataContract]
public class User
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
 
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string LastName {get; set; }

    // NB Password won't be in EdmModel but still available to EF
    public string Password {get; set;}
}
```

This has the advantage of keeping all the mapping logic in one place in your project

Comment: This worked for me as far as the response is concerned but screwed up something else, I have queries with complex ordering and they stopped working after I used those attributes

Answer (score 0):

You can create new view in DB with the only data you need. Then set EntitySetRights.None for Users table and create necessary relationships for created view. 
Now you can do common odata requests (GET odata/UsersFromView) and getting users data without password. Post request you can do using Users table.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing else worked for me, so here's an elegant solution.

Use the `HideSensitiveProperties()` extension method in your `TableController` like this.

```
    // GET tables/User
    public IQueryable<User> GetAllUsers()
    {
        return Query().HideSensitiveProperties();
    }

    // GET tables/User/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
    public SingleResult<User> GetUser(string id)
    {
        return Lookup(id).HideSensitiveProperties();
    }

    // PATCH tables/User/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
    public Task<User> PatchUser(string id, Delta<User> patch)
    {
        return UpdateAsync(id, patch).HideSensitivePropertiesForItem();
    }

    // POST tables/User
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostUser(User item)
    {
        User current = await InsertAsync(item);
        current.HideSensitivePropertiesForItem();
        return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
    }

    // DELETE tables/User/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
    public Task DeleteUser(string id)
    {
        return DeleteAsync(id);
    }
```

Though this will not remove the property name from the response, but it will set its value to `null`.

```
public static class HideSensitivePropertiesExtensions
{
    public static async Task<TData> HideSensitivePropertiesForItem<TData>(this Task<TData> task)
        where TData : ModelBase
    {
        return (await task).HideSensitivePropertiesForItem();
    }

    public static TData HideSensitivePropertiesForItem<TData>(this TData item)
        where TData : ModelBase
    {
        item.Password = null;
        return item;
    }

    public static SingleResult<TData> HideSensitiveProperties<TData>(this SingleResult<TData> singleResult)
        where TData : ModelBase
    {
        return new SingleResult<TData>(singleResult.Queryable.HideSensitiveProperties());
    }

    public static IQueryable<TData> HideSensitiveProperties<TData>(this IQueryable<TData> query)
        where TData : ModelBase
    {
        return query.ToList().HideSensitiveProperties().AsQueryable();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TData> HideSensitiveProperties<TData>(this IEnumerable<TData> query)
        where TData : ModelBase
    {
        foreach (var item in query)
            yield return item.HideSensitivePropertiesForItem();
    }
}
```

Here `ModelBase` is the base class for all the DTOs.

Answer (score 0):

You should not query your Domain model directly in the controller.  Instead, create a QueryModel DTO that maps to the Domain model.

You can read more about these concepts in DDD and CQRS

Comment: This sounds like a great idea, but i can't find a good example how to combine OData, EntityFrameworkCore and a Domain model. do you have one?

Answer (score 0):

I am also late in here, but I cannot find any good and clean way to achieve that.

So i have this for a temporary and ugly solution :

```
public class MyCustomerClassName
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]  
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //normal properties that are exposed to API and read/write to EF
    public string Name { get; set; }  
    public string Adress { get; set; }



    //and here, for ONE property named MildlySensitiveInformation :

    //the EF property, that is not exposed
    [IgnoreDataMember] //says 'dont show that when you serialize (convert to json -> exposed in API)
    [Column("MildlySensitiveInformation")] //says 'the REAL column name here is THAT
    public string MildlySensitiveInformation_MappedToDB { get; set; } //a 'false' column name, allowing me to expose the real column name in the next property

    //the WebApi/Odata property that is exposed
    [NotMapped] //Says 'Dont map to EF'
    public string MildlySensitiveInformation { 
        get { return ""; }  //says 'never fetch here'
        set { MildlySensitiveInformation_MappedToDB = value; }  //Says : assign to my real DB properties
    }
```

I did'nt wanted to go with a 'class-over-a-class' for the moment (DTO)...

I have an ODATA exposure, so I dont want to play inside the controller part :

```
   public class MyCustomerClassNameClassName : ODataController
{
    private MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext();

    // GET: odata/MyCustomerClassName
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<MyCustomerClassName> GetMembresPleinAir()
    {
        //don't mess here, there is enough 'black magic' going on with $select/$filter/$etc...
        var OrigQuery = db.AllMyCustomers;
        return OrigQuery;
    }
```

However, I am not proud of that solution, because :
1 - it is simply ugly and I apology to the next programmer who will touch that.
2 - it mixes Business logic with 'raw' database mapping

So I guess that the only 'real and clean' solution would be to have a DTO Class that allows a better controller over how my data is read/write.

But then, if I want to be consistant in my project, I would have to clone every of my 13 classes with a 'pure class' and a 'DTO class'.

Take a look here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#prevent-over-posting

Answer (score -3):

use [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<User> GetUsers()
{
    //Leave password empty
    Mapper.CreateMap<User, User>().ForMember(x => x.Password, opt => opt.Ignore());

    return db.Users.ToList().Select(u=>Mapper.Map<User>(u)).AsQueryable();      
}
```

Comment: I get "message": "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'ExampleAPI.Models.User Map[User](System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.",

Comment: Missing a ToList in the middle, check it now

Comment: I changed the code and the error has been solved but still getting the password in the Odata response.

Comment: Try with Ignore instead of UseDestination value (I updated my answer)

Comment: Thanks but the password is still being displayed in the response.

Comment: Sorry, it was ForMember, not SourceMember, hope you still need this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68278/discussion-between-dariogriffo-and-robert-plant).