# Limit Columns when creating oData Web Service with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, odata

I am new to oData web services and I can not figure out how to remove certain unneeded columns from returning in my oData result.  I tried to remove them from the model and that resulted in an error (problem in mapping fragments).

Let's just say my table is set up like this:

```
ID
Name
UpdateDate
CreateDate
```

I would prefer for my oData service to only return ID and Name, but entity framework wants to add all fields.

Comment: Couple of ways around that. I recommend a DTO. [Here are some other options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781607/exclude-property-from-webapi-odata-ef-response-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Are you using WCF or WebAPI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- mark properties to be ignored with [NotMapped](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute:

  ```
  public class MyTable
  {
      public int ID { get; set; }

      public string Name { get; set; }

      [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMappedAttribute]
      public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }

      [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMappedAttribute]
      public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- or ignore properties explicitly:

  ```
  ODataConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder= new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

  modelBuilder.EntityType<MyTable>().Ignore(_ => _.CreateDate);

  modelBuilder.EntityType<MyTable>().Ignore(_ => _.UpdateDate);
  ```