# Web API $expand property bypasses JsonIgnore and ShouldSerialize{MemberName}

Tags: json.net, asp.net-web-api2, iqueryable

I am using Web API and EnableQuery to return Queryable list of Users. There is some sensitive data, which I want to omit, thus I am using both JsonIgnore and ShouldSerialize{DataMember} pattern to remove email addresses, orders, etc.
Now all works fine if I return a single object or a query without parameters. 
Once I start using $expand or $select, all those properties get included.

Any ideas why this is happening?

P.S., I have noticed when $expand is used, values get wrapped around SelectAllAndExpand<T> object.

Comment: Are you using [tag:odata] and [tag:entity-framework]?  If so, this might be related: [Exclude property from WebApi OData (EF) response in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27781607/3744182).  Because I believe that OData response serialization does not use json.net, see [JSON.NET as a WebAPI 2 OData serializer vs ODataMediaTypeFormatter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20656229/3744182).  If you could provide a [mcve] that would increase your chances of getting an answer; see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Thanks for your help!