# $select and $expand exposes sensitive data in Web API

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to hide my PasswordHash field from User table by marking it with [JsonIgnore] attribute. localhost/User query gets me a list of users and excludes PasswordHash from the results, but if I write my query as such: localhost/User?$select=PasswordHash, it returns data, even though it should ignore it!!!

I am exposing my Entity Framework table User using an ApiController with [EnableQuery] GetAll(); method, which returns IQueryable<User> as result.
Please help!

Comment: Perhaps you should use a DTO instead of directly exposing your EF model to the outside world.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude property from WebApi OData (EF) response in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781607/exclude-property-from-webapi-odata-ef-response-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with the Brian Rogers' suggestion to use a [DTO](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) that exposes only *necessary* fields. It's cheep and secure.

If you decide to keep the existing model, you may look at [EDM Security guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-security-guidance#edm-security) which suggests to use the `[IgnoreDataMember]` attribute.